# Is it easier to construct global sections on tangent bundle then other fiber bundle?

Tags: differential-forms, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

When talking about differential forms, it seemst that it is not a serious problem about whether can there be forms on a manifold $M$ at all - it's like they are just functions from some domain and you can construct them freely with ease.

But differential forms are also global sections of cotangent bundles (or their exterior product bundles), then it's like it is very easy to freely construct global sections on entities that is like tangent bundle, not like some general fiber bundle or exotic fiber bundle on which global sections is hard to find.

Is it true and does some properties of tangent bundle make it easy?

Comment: Generally, on a vector bundle there is an abundance of sections due to access to partitions of unity in the smooth and topological categories. The tangent bundle is no different. The one distinction between the natural bundles (those derived from $TM$ and $T^*M$) and a generic one are the existence of local sections coming from local coordinates on $M$ and the existence of the exterior derivative.

Comment: Both vector bundles and fiber bundles are locally trivial, so we can always find local sections (because trivial bundles have sections). In the case of vector bundles, we can use the additional structure to extend local sections to global sections using bump functions. For a general fiber bundle, we cannot always extend local sections (fiber bundles need not admit any global sections at all).